# PHP text to image using stylistc set in OTF font

Tags: php, fonts

I'm trying to output a text to image using a font that has 7 stylistic sets. I'm using the code below but can't find how I can use a style in the output. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'This is a test!';

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'joined.otf';


// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: It's a PHP function, not a user created function.

Comment: Try to provide the full path of the font file if it is not in the script directory.